# Apache UNC network path under Windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, network-share, unc

Ok, so I'm running apache on two Windows 7 boxes for use as a test environment.  The idea is to keep all projects on a shared network path so I can access it with my desktop or notebook anytime.

Running apache as a console using my user account, *MyAccount*, with access to the network path gives the following error: `Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/EMMA/users/*MyAccount*/Documents/*MyWebsite*/] does not exist`

All I've done is included the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file in `httpd.conf` and added the following to the vhosts config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "\\EMMA\users\MyAccount\Documents\MyWebsite"
    ServerName MyWebsite
    ErrorLog "logs\MyWebsite-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs\MyWebsite-access.log" common
    <directory "\\EMMA\users\MyAccount\Documents\MyWebsite">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The windows hosts file is setup correctly, as changing the path to the local apache htdocs works fine and I can access the local site without problems in a browser.

My confusion is thus; The apache manual states that apache can not access a network path as a user without access to the network path.  However, since the apache console is running as *MyAccount* which definitely has access to the network path, why isn't this working? I've check the process Menu and it's definitely running under *MyAccount* and not System.  For some reason based on the error message apache is trying to look at a local directory and not a network directory?

Any ideas?  If I can figure out why apache is trying to access the network path as a local path I think that should fix it, but I'm at a total loss here.

Comment: ID10T Error!!! I needed to use forward slashes instead of backslashes in the DocumentRoot and <Directory> configurations. My heard hurts, but my problem is solved. I shall leave this here for posterity and humility.

Comment: Since you've found your own answer, you should post and accept your answer so others who come across this later can more easily identify that there's a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID10T Error!!! I needed to use forward (/) slashes instead of backslashes () in the DocumentRoot and  configurations. My heard hurts, but my problem is solved. I shall leave this here for posterity and humility.